# social engine upgrade theme

Tags: socialengine

I have a project in social engine 3.x . I have upgraded it into social engine 4.x. I want to upgrade social engine 3.x old theme into social engine 4.x theme.

Answer (score 0):

The New SE4 has an entirely new template engine. If you want to migrate, make sure you redesign the css and other files as the SE4 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Social Engine 4 uses new way of handling templates, and a lot of stuff you got used to in SE 3.x - like Smarty parts and stuff, is handled differently. Copy a existing theme, rename it and start editing CSS and layout files of modules/widgets.